# Angularjs Promise object overwriting property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two models in services which are related and then have an external event which triggers a requery with added options.

Service Surah has many Ayahs:

```
.service 'Surah', (Restangular, Ayah) ->

    class Surah
      constructor: (obj) ->
        for key of obj
          @[key] = obj[key]

      getAyahs: (from, to) ->
        self = @
        @ayahs = Ayah.all
          surah_id: @id, from: from, to: to
        .then (ayahs) ->
          console.log(ayahs)
          self.ayahs = ayahs
      @new: (id)->
        return Restangular.one('surahs', id).get().then (data)->
          return new Surah(data)

      @all: ->
        return Restangular.all("surahs").getList()



.service 'Ayah', (Restangular, userOptions, utils) ->
    # AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    class Ayah
      constructor: (obj)->
        for key of obj
          @[key] = obj[key]

      @all: (hash) ->
        Restangular.one('surahs', hash.surah_id).getList 'ayat', 
          content: userOptions.content.join(","), quran: userOptions.quran, audio: userOptions.audio, from: hash.from, to: hash.to
        .then (data)->
          fontFaces = []
          console.log(data)
          ayahs = data.map (ayah) ->
            # The ayah object is returned from Restangular and given all the properties that restangular gives it. For example, you can call
            # ayah.save() or ayah.remove() which will make API calls accordingly. This is power and will be perserved when creating the Ayah object
            return new Ayah(ayah)

          utils.createFontFaces(ayahs)
          return ayahs
```

In my controller, upon option change, I do another query of the `.all()` in the `Ayah` service which is within an array and property of the `Surah` service. So imagine:

```
{ayahs: [A,A,A,A,A,A]}
```

Once I make a call, in the controller, I get a Promise object, then the array populates with the new Ayahs. This is not a fun experience for the user cause literally all the content in the array disappears then repopulates. How can I avoid that? How can I wait for the promise to return THEN update the array which holds all the Ayahs?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem that I was able to fix by overwriting the variable I want to store data in the via the success function in the .then(). But I still have the problem of it not showing in the view and $rootScope isn't working. :(